# iOS Metal compute pipeline slower than CPU implementation for search task

Tags: ios, performance, shader, metal

I made simple experiment, by implementing naive char search algorithm searching 1.000.000 rows of 50 characters each (50 mil char map) on both CPU and GPU (using iOS8 Metal compute pipeline).

CPU implementation uses simple loop, Metal implementation gives each kernel 1 row to process (source code below).

To my surprise, Metal implementation is on average 2-3 times slower than simple, linear CPU (if I use 1 core) and 3-4 times slower if I employ 2 cores (each of them searching half of database)!
I experimented with diffrent threads per group (16, 32, 64, 128, 512) yet still get very similar results.

iPhone 6:

```
CPU 1 core:  approx 0.12 sec
CPU 2 cores: approx 0.075 sec
GPU: approx 0.35 sec (relEase mode, validation disabled)
```

I can see Metal shader spending more than 90% of accessing memory (see below).

**What can be done to optimise it?**

Any insights will be appreciated, as there are not many sources in the internet (besides standard Apple programming guides), providing details on memory access internals & trade-offs specific to the Metal framework.

**METAL IMPLEMENTATION DETAILS:**

Host code gist:
https://gist.github.com/lukaszmargielewski/0a3b16d4661dd7d7e00d

Kernel (shader) code:
https://gist.github.com/lukaszmargielewski/6b64d06d2d106d110126

GPU frame capture profiling results:

[image]

Comment: don't paste screenshots of code. they're basically useless... cut&paste the actual code.

Comment: @MarcB I replaced screenshot with github gist. Hope it is fine (had big trouble to format that chunk of code properly).

Comment: The first thing I'd try is to move searchPhrase to device memory. Apple says not to use constant space for arrays. Let us know if that does anything.

Comment: @Jessy : Changing to device space changed nothing. What's more: I lost the chance to set shader buffer using setBytes: (which Apple claim is faster, as you do not have to create <MTLBuffer> object).

Comment: Interesting. I guess the relevant documentation needs an overhaul. Lies!

Comment: Did you ever manage to make any improvements?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: Hi Kykasz, I am trying to do the same GPU profiling for a Metal compute task. However, I wasn't able to achieve the GPU profiling results you showed in the figure above. can you please give me some hints on how to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertWang - There are links to both shader and client code in the question. Not sure how else can I help?

Answer (score 4):

The GPU shader is also striding vertically through memory, whereas the CPU is moving horizontally. Consider the addresses actually touched more or less concurrently by each thread executing in lockstep in your shader as you read charTable. The GPU will probably run a good deal faster if your charTable matrix is transposed.

Also, because this code executes in a SIMD fashion, each GPU thread will probably have to run the loop to the full search phrase length, whereas the CPU will get to take advantage of early outs. The GPU code might actually run a little faster if you remove the early outs and just keep the code simple. Much depends on the search phrase length and likelihood of a match.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take my guesses too, gpu isn't optimized for if/else, it doesn't predict branches (it probably execute both), try to rewrite the algorithm in a more linear way without any conditional or reduce them to bare minimum.

Comment: Profiling tools clearly show (visible on attached screenshot) that this is not the bottleneck. More than 90% of time is spent on memory access.